# Regex is removing ellipsis character

Tags: .net, regex

I am not able to read regex very well and have inherited some code that I'm trying to interpret. I have two questions.

First, can you please explain what the pieces of the regex pattern are doing?

Second, we have an issue where an ellipsis character is being replaced with a space by this code and we would like to retain the ellipsis. What needs to change in the statement to retain the ellipsis?

```
Dim Test As String = "Test...test" 'this is three dots and not an ellipsis, but just as an example
Dim NotGoodCharacters As String = "[^\w\,<>:;~`@#$%^&*()_=+\-{}|[\]\\?/! ""'']"
Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Test, NotGoodCharacters, " ")
```

Much thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is replacing any character that is **NOT** in the set:

```
\w\,<>:;~@#$%^`&*()_=+-{}|[]\?/! ""''
```

with a space.  Any time you see `[^...]` the regex is matching any character that is not one of the characters between `[^` and `]`.  The `\w` matches any word character, `\,` matches a comma, `\\` matches a back slash.  I guess an ellipse is none of those characters so it makes sense that it would get stripped out.

UPDATE:

After @Alan's comment I noticed a few more that should probably be explained. `\-` matches a dash, `\]` matches a closing square bracket.

If you want to exclude the ellipse you could try changing your regex to this:

```
Dim NotGoodCharacters As String = "[^\w\,<>:;~`@#$%^&*()_=+\-{}|[\]\\?/! ""''\x85]"
```

The `\x85` matches the ascii code for a horizontal ellipsis.

Comment: Correction: `\w` matches any word **character**.  That's probably what you meant, but many people do start out expecting `\w` to match a whole word rather than a single character.  No sense adding to that confusion.  Also, I'm pretty sure the `\\?` sequence represents an escaped backslash and a question mark (which doesn't need to be escaped inside a character class).

Comment: Updated.  Thanks for the correction.  I also updated to explain a few other escapes.

Comment: So the OP should just be able to \. to the negated character class and be ok?

Comment: If it's the ascii ellipsis character I don't think that will work.  Take a look at the updated regex I posted.  I think that would work.

Comment: Good point.  The \. may be needed if its the 3 periods, but it could also be the ellipsis character.  A larger point tho is that \x## will allow a hex character.  So if the OP looks at the data and sees its something else entirely (like maybe Word 'helped' out by replaceing with an extended ASCII char) they can still use the hex value to exclude it.

Comment: `\x85` is how the ellipsis is encoded in the `windows-1252` code page.  Use that in a regex and the system will probably think you mean the NEXT LINE character (NEL, `U+0085`). The Unicode code point of for the ellipsis is `U+2026`, so `\u2026` is how you would represent it in a regex.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a nice little flash tool to help you build regex's.
[RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: That does not use JavaScript. It uses Flash. The underlying language (and regex engine) is ActionScript 3. AS3 and ES3/5 regexes are very similar, but not identical.

Comment: My bad, don't know why I thought it was flash.